# SVN checkout under Linux using Ant

Tags: linux, svn, ant

When I run the build.xml in linux ubuntu, which should checkout the project from svn is giving the following error:-

```
svn:

BUILD FAILED
java.net.MalformedURLException: Invalid svn url: svn://xxx-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/srv/svn
    at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.SVNUrl.parseUrl(SVNUrl.java:117)
    at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.SVNUrl.<init>(SVNUrl.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper$11.set(IntrospectionHelper.java:1069)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper.setAttribute(IntrospectionHelper.java:388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.RuntimeConfigurable.maybeConfigure(RuntimeConfigurable.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.RuntimeConfigurable.maybeConfigure(RuntimeConfigurable.java:349)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChild(UnknownElement.java:568)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.handleChildren(UnknownElement.java:346)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.configure(UnknownElement.java:198)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:160)
```

Actually the path of svn is what I connect from my local box. So I don't know what path I shoul give here. The svn is in the same linux box.

My directory path where the build.xml is:-/home/ubuntu/antCheckout
And the path where svn is:-/srv/svn

I also tried this path:- ssh://srv/svn but exception was same.

This is my build.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Test" default="Main" basedir=".">
 <!-- Sets variables which can be used. -->
  <property name="checkout" location="./svncheckout" />
 <!-- Define the classpath which includes the jars 
      that are required for svnant.jar -->
 <path id="/usr/local/ant/apache-ant-1.7.1/">
  <pathelement location="lib/svnant.jar" />
  <pathelement location="lib/svnClientAdapter.jar" />
  <pathelement location="lib/svnjavahl.jar" />
  <pathelement location="lib/svnkit.jar" />
 </path>

 <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml"     
      classpathref="/usr/local/ant/apache-ant-1.7.1/" />


 <!-- Deletes the existing build, docs and dist directory-->
 <target name="clean">
  <delete dir="${checkout}" />
 </target>

 <!-- Creates the  build, docs and dist directory-->
 <target name="makedir">
  <mkdir dir="${checkout}" />
 </target>


 <!-- Checkout the latest source code of svnant itself-->
 <target name="svn">
  <svn username="guest" password="">
   <checkout url="svn://srv/svn" revision="HEAD" destPath="${checkout}" />
  </svn>
 </target>

 <target name="Main" depends="clean, makedir, svn">
  <description>Main target</description>
 </target>
</project>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you checkout from the command line? Something like: `svn co https://srv/svn`

Comment: Khez I tried this path:-svn://srv/svn/ and it give:-svn:
      [svn] <Checkout> started ...
      [svn] svn: Unknown host srv
      [svn] svn: Unknown host srv
      [svn] srv
      [svn] <Checkout> failed !

Comment: I think it is not going on the pat of srv. My directory path where the build.xml is:-/home/ubuntu/antCheckout And the path where svn is:-/srv/svn.

Comment: does the command line work? forget about ant, command line. You said it's on the same machine... so just run `svn checkout` and give us the report.

Comment: This is the response:-ubuntu@ip-10-122-177-48:/srv/svn$ svn co https://srv/svn
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://srv/svn': Could not resolve hostname `srv': Host not found (https://srv)

Comment: ^ there ya go. You probably expect `srv` to point to localhost. Either edit `/etc/hosts` and point `srv` to something or use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` instead of `srv`.

Comment: svn checkout svn://127.0.0.1/svn
svn: Can't connect to host '127.0.0.1': Connection refused

Comment: We can't help you further from here. You need to find out where your SVN repository is. P.S. It can be svn:// http:// https:// the proto scheme is configurable...

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux, do you have the Subversion command line client?

Try this:

```
$ svn --version
```

If you have the Subversion command line client, try this command:

```
$ svn ls svn://svn/srv
```

And see what you get. I bet you'll get an error telling you that `svn://srv/svn` isn't found or isn't a valid URL.

This line:

```
<checkout url="svn://srv/svn" revision="HEAD" destPath="${checkout}" />
```

Is equivalent to the command line:

```
$ svn checkout -rHEAD svn://srv/svn .svncheckout
```

You will have to find the valid Subversion repository URL before this command will work. Then, change the `url` parameter in the `<checkout>` sub-task to match that URL. Subversion uses URLs to point to the repository address.

By the way, exactly what is this suppose to be doing? Why is this checking out the working directory to the `.svncheckout` directory? That's a *hidden* directory in Unix.

---

By the way: `svn co svn://127.0.0.1` isn't going to work unless the program `snvserve` is running on the local system. The `svnserve` program